# Editing a property of an interface type variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Lets say I have the following interface:

```
  export interface MyInterfaceType{
        field1: string;
        field2: string;
        field3: string;
        field4: number;
        field5: string;
        field6: string;
        field7: string;
        field8: string;
        field9: number;
  }
```

Now lets say I have the following `temp` variable:

```
let temp: MyInterfaceType = someVariableOfType_MyInterfaceType as MyInterfaceType;
```

In above I cannot directly edit a property of `temp` like below

```
temp.field5 = xxxxxx // doesnt work
```

because I would get *"Cannot assign to read only property 'field5' of object"*

To bypass the issue I do the following:

```
  let finalObject: MyInterfaceType = {
    field1:temp.field1,
    field2:temp.field2,
    field3:temp.field3,
    field4:temp.field4,

    field5:xxxxxx, // something random

    field6:temp.field6,
    field7:temp.field7,
    field8:temp.field8,
    field9:temp.field9
  };
```

Is there a cleaner way of editing a property of an interface type in similar situations?

Comment: *I cannot directly edit a property of temp like below*: why? what do you expect to happen when you do it, and what happens instead?

Comment: doing so I would get : "Cannot assign to read only property 'field5' of object"

Comment: field5 is not read-only. So no, the code you posted wouldn't cause that error. Post the actual code you're asking about.

Comment: The actual code is coming from an angular application similar to below:

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<SomeType> {

        let temp: MyInterfaceType = route.params as MyInterfaceType

Comment: Please edit the question with a [mcve] so that someone can help you. As it stands, your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Check your someVariableOfType_MyInterfaceType variable. You don't say from where it comes. Don't cast it with **as MyInterfaceType**, and avoid casting types if you don't have a good reason, or you would just hide your code's errors and defeat the purpose of TypeScript.